# rm -rf ~$* on macbook - what now?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

So I recently as a total mistake ran the command:

```
rm -rf ~$*
```

So now my terminal shell looks crappy and all my files are gone. Great succes.
My terminal shows the user as:

User%

How do I get it back to "User@Machine" format?

Comment: Restore the data from your backup.

Comment: How about no backup..

Comment: Then you're screwed

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, just a bit to add onto the advice from @swa66.

I don't know what kind of mac you have, but if you have one that you can pull the hard drive out yourself then you might want to consider doing that.  There are numerous tools on the market that can recover deleted files and directories as long as you have not written over the data.  If you put a new bare drive into your mac, assuming you can, then you can install a fresh copy of macOS and your third party apps, etc as swa66 advised.  Then you can purchase one of the reputable disk recovery apps and attach your pulled out drive via an external enclosure or dock (I like the docks the best)  and then proceed to recover your important files.  It takes some work and it requires a bit of expenditure if you don't have a suitable bare drive around and an external enclosure or dock and the recovery software.  But depending on the value of your lost data it maybe worth it to you.  As swa66 said, drive recovery services are extremely expensive so if you have not overwritten you data with new data or repartitioned you can have good success retrieving the most common file types yourself.

If you cannot pull your drive out, but you have access to another mac, then there is the option of using target disk mode to access your drive from another mac to image the drive for later recovery attempts or direct recovery but you have to make sure that the recovery software supports target disk mode.  If your lost data is important, then be very careful what you do with your computer to avoid overwriting the lost data.  -rf does not actually over-write or remove the data from the disk so it is still there but the locations of the files on the disk are now available to be overwritten by anything.  Don't install recovery software onto the same drive that you are trying to recover from for example.

Comment: You do have a point about swapping harddisks and/or using target disk mode. The problem I have with it is simple: I've *never* had any luck at all with any tool I tried doing that in real situations (hence outside of the lab). I essentially gave up on the tool's abilities I guess.
For the benefit of others having similar problems,  I'l update my answer a bit using this to make sure all angles are covered.

Answer (score 1):

**Restore from backup**

To get your files back, you have but one easy option: restore from backup.
Let's hope you made TimeMachine backups on a regular basis.

`rm -rf` on the command line removes files and directories recursively, no mercy, no second guesses, no second chances.

The `~$*`: I'm unsure what it expanded to. $* in bash expands to the arguments given to the script. but since it likely expanded to nothing, you might have nuked the home directory `~` of the user that executed this and everything in it that you can erase recursively will be gone. That's typically way too much to still have a stable environment.

So: restore from backup as your only simple option.
If you can't do that, There are 2 options left: Start over and Recover (some) data

**Start over**

Myself, I'd just restore the system from scratch if I didn't want to are was unable to restore a backup. It is the only way to be sure to have a stable system again where directories like Desktop, Downloads, Library,  etc. still exist with their proper permissions and contents.

**Recover (some) data**

If you stop using the system ASAP there's an option that some services might find some valuable data on your harddisk. No guarantees will be given at all. So consider it a last resort at best. It will not restore your system to working condition, but it might recover some valuable data.

What to do if you want to keep this option open:

- Stop using the system NOW, shut it down. Every write your system does to the harddisk is (potentially) overwriting the data you might want to recover.
- If you have a system with removable harddisks. Most modern macs are not easy, nor recommended for end-users to swap harddisk themselves, it's even likely to void warranties on the system, so take care!

  -> Replace the disk in the machine with a new one and start rebuilding on that new disk. Use the old disk only as a target of the recovery, never boot from it, or otherwise write to it.
- If you have a system without an easily removable harddisk, you'll have to stop using the system till the valuable data has been recovered. If you're going for the DIY path below, you will have to bring the system up in "target disk mode" See here how to do that: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462

You now have two options:

- DIY: I honestly have never had any success with this in real cases, but it is possible to find software that will claim to do this for you. Obviously nothing will ever be guaranteed and the best you can hope for is to recover some of the valuable data files. This software is typically not cheap, but significantly cheaper than the next option.
- Professional data recovery service. Get the disk to the service of your choice. Expect this to be extremely expensive, without any guarantee to results.

**Lessons learned**

All incidents should always allow for an after the fact point in time where you learn from the experience. Without trying to preach too much:

- Be careful with rm -rf ... it is powerful
- Make backups regularly. On macOS timeMachine is easy and painless and costs you next to nothing compared to this pain. TimeMachine can backup to an external drive, an apple time capsule, a partition on a NAS, ... If you leave it connected, you'll have hourly backups.

Comment: Hi swa66. Desktop and default folders is still alive. Everything else in the home folder is true - nuked. Is there no way to build up the home folder by downloading things from scratch?

Comment: You might have some success, but you will _never_ be able to rebuild trust that you have everything as it was.  Hence anything can still go wrong, and everything can behave differently from now till the time you reinstall from scratch. It's not worth it. Copy the data you have left (if any) onto at least two external storage devices. Then release licenses you have installed (if any), wipe the thing clean, reinstall macOS, reinstall your 3rd party applications, copy your data. Finally: start TimeMachine backups on a regular basis, it's painless compared to this.